# How to refresh ajax call in JSF after database change?

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a table that is generated in my JSF page using an ajax request. When I delete and entry off this table, I want the ajax call to refresh to show this entry has been removed. Here is my code below. At the moment when the "deleteAccount" commandbutton is clicked, the entry gets removed from the database but this does not get reflected on screen until I click the "searchcontractors" button again. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
<h:form id="searchForm">
    <div class="white"><H2>View All Contractors</H2></div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
             <div class="myButtonPadding">
                <h:commandButton id="searchContractors" class="myButton"
                  action="#{adminBean.searchAllContractors()}" value="View All">
                     <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":results" />
                </h:commandButton>
              </div>
             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</h:form>

<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="red">
           <H2>Search Results</H2>
        </div>      
        <ui:repeat var="a" value="#{adminBean.contractorList}" varStatus="status">
            <tr>
                <td>
                   <div class="generaltext5">#{a.businessName}</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h:commandButton id="deleteAccount" class="myButton2" value="Delete" action="#{adminBean.deleteAccount(a.id)}">
                         <f:param name="compId" value="#{a.id}" />
                     </h:commandButton></td>
              </tr>  
         </ui:repeat>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<f:ajax>` tag with your button.

```
<h:commandButton id="deleteAccount" class="myButton2" value="Delete" type="button" >
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{adminBean.deleteAccount(a.id)}" render=":searchForm"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

This will launch an ajax call and update the whole form with id `searchForm`, but you can update only the table if you so wish. To be future proof, in case you wanted to make any submits from your lower table, make sure to include it in a `h:form` tag. BTW. why did you pass a param with

```
<f:param name="compId" value="#{a.id}" />
```

if you already did it with method call? (`adminBean.deleteAccount(a.id)`)